# The value specified for SourceVersion is not a valid commit ID

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I modified my pipeline in azure DevOps now I try to run it gives bellow error:

```
  The value specified for SourceVersion is not a valid commit ID
```

I could not found solution to resolve it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to build previous version of commit, you should input full hash of the commit(40 characters) in the Commit column. Or you could leave it empty, then the build will run with the latest commit.

Comment: Thanks it run when I leave it empty